# how to make a tree of `li` elements correctly near each other

Tags: css, tree, html-lists

For a filetree that is dynamically generated, I set the width to 360px and a scroll on the x.
I know, the syntax is not correct, (nested `ul` should be in `li` ) but I am still wondering why the `hhhhh` in code below is not at the right side of the `|-` but under it. And the `iiiii` and further also...

```css
.tree {
  width: 360px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.li-tree {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul class="ul-tree">
    <li class="li-tree">|-<span>aaaaa</span></li>
    <ul class="ul-tree">
      <li class="li-tree">|-<span>bbbbb</span></li>
      <ul class="ul-tree">
        <li class="li-tree">|-<span>ccccc</span></li>
        <ul class="ul-tree">
          <li class="li-tree">|-<span>ddddd</span></li>
          <ul class="ul-tree">
            <li class="li-tree">|-<span>eeeee</span></li>
            <ul class="ul-tree">
              <li class="li-tree">|-<span>fffff</span></li>
              <ul class="ul-tree">
                <li class="li-tree">|-<span>ggggg</span></li>
                <ul class="ul-tree">
                  <li class="li-tree">|-<span>hhhhh</span></li>
                  <ul class="ul-tree">
                    <li class="li-tree">|<span>iiiii</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </ul>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see in the fiddle that `hhhhh` is not right of the `|-` anymore, but under it: https://jsfiddle.net/a9fudsb6/5/

Comment: Your html is invalid, you need to nest the ul inside the li. But, if you want the text to always be next to the pipe, use `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: I know the html is invalid, but it explains for me still not why it happens only with `hhhhh` and not already before

Comment: because there is no room for the text to fit on one line (as the li has reached the end of the natural width of the div)  so it wraps as it takes up as little space as possible before forcing the div to get wider

Comment: @Pete, but that's exactly what I wanted to achieve: after width range is finished, still right of the `|-` and continue with it in the scroll. How can I force that?

Comment: read my first comment

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your **width** there is no space for your tree.
If you change it e.g. to

```
width = 400;
```

it appears inside.

If you want to keep your width, add the following:

```
.tree {
  width: 360px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;   // that one here
}
```